# Display content of Site B on Site A

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am completely new developing SharePoint sites.

I have a parent site A which has all the needed information and have some FAQ's in another site B.

Rather than having URL redirection to site B, I'm planning to show the content of site B in site A.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

FYI, I'm using SharePoint server 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these two sites in the same site collection?

If yes. You can refer to these links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TntwRm78b_4
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jackiebo/2007/02/27/displaying-a-list-on-another-site-in-the-same-site-collection/

If no. You can refer to the following situations:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7f107904-bf44-484a-b93b-416119b3232b/display-list-from-another-site-collection-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment

https://www.consultdolphin.com/easy-method-of-showing-lists-libraries-across-site-collections/

Comment: Thanks for the Awesome video and other references.

Comment: If you have any questions, you can update them at any time.If you think the replies are helpful to you, please remember to mark them as answers.

Answer (score 1):

you can use any of the below option which i have found. for me i think data View Webpart will be good to implement.

1. SharePoint 2010 Cross-Site Content Rollup using SharePoint Designer 2010 and a DataView Web Part
2. Referencing lists from external site collections – Cross-site collection lookup with REST and the DVWP!
3. display a SharePoint List from another site using the Data View Web Part
   http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/display-sharepoint-list-site-data-view-web-part/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've achieved lists by importing Web Part and then Lists and Libraries. Looks like the first 2 links are not available.